# tableview.reloadData() does not repeat cellForRowAt function

Tags: swift, uitableview, reloaddata

I'm trying to create an app using Swift 4.

The purpose of the table is to use `UITableViewCell.SelectionStyle.none` if my a cell data has 0 count from the API.

And later, i used `UIRefreshControl()` to refresh the data by pulling down the table.

but whenever i pull down the table, the data refreshes but the style of the cell is not changing.

I already tried `reloadData()` but it does not work. The function does not reload the `cellForRowAt`.

Here is my cellForRowAt

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "custom") as! AppsCustomCell
        cell.imglink = data[indexPath.row].imglink
        cell.title = data[indexPath.row].AppName
        cell.subtitle = data[indexPath.row].AppDesc
        cell.count = String(data[indexPath.row].count)
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        cell.layoutSubviews()

        if data[indexPath.row].boolPress == 0 || data[indexPath.row].count < 1 {
//        if false {

            cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCell.SelectionStyle.none
            cell.contentView.isOpaque = false
            cell.mainImageView.alpha = 0.5
            cell.titleView.alpha = 0.5
            cell.subtitleView.alpha = 0.5
            cell.count = "0"

        } else {

            cell.count = String(data[indexPath.row].count)
            cell.countView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
            cell.countView.textColor = UIColor.white

        }

        return cell

    }
```

I expect to reload the entire table including the styles of the cells whenever i use refresh to pull

**EDIT** : here is how i refresh my table

```
@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
var refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()

override func viewDidLoad() {
        refreshControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(refresh), for: UIControl.Event.valueChanged)
        tableView.addSubview(refreshControl) // not required when using UITableViewController
}

@objc func refresh() {
        // Insert code here to get data from the API.
        self.tableView.reloadData()
        self.refreshControl.endRefreshing()
}
```

**EDIT**: Here is the result in UI

[This is the old data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A2OFv.png)

AND HERE IS THE tableView if i pull down the table using `UIRefreshControl()`

[Refreshed Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gL0KR.png)

Comment: Cannot help if you just post function `cellForRowAt`. Post some more code how you refresh your `tableView`

Comment: @TungVuDuc sorry, i edited the post. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are adding the refresh control to the table view in the wrong way. Try below:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    refreshControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(refresh), for: UIControl.Event.valueChanged)
    tableView.refreshControl = refreshControl
}
```

Also, set the selection style when you have a count greater than 0.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "custom") as! AppsCustomCell
    cell.imglink = data[indexPath.row].imglink
    cell.title = data[indexPath.row].AppName
    cell.subtitle = data[indexPath.row].AppDesc
    cell.count = String(data[indexPath.row].count)
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    cell.layoutSubviews()

    if data[indexPath.row].boolPress == 0 || data[indexPath.row].count < 1 {
//        if false {

        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCell.SelectionStyle.none
        cell.contentView.isOpaque = false
        cell.mainImageView.alpha = 0.5
        cell.titleView.alpha = 0.5
        cell.subtitleView.alpha = 0.5
        cell.count = "0"

    } else {
        cell.selectionStyle = .default
        cell.count = String(data[indexPath.row].count)
        cell.countView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        cell.countView.textColor = UIColor.white
        cell.mainImageView.alpha = 1.0
        cell.titleView.alpha = 1.0
        cell.subtitleView.alpha = 1.0
    }

    return cell

}
```

Comment: im still having the same result. refresh does not update the `cell.selectionStyle` when the new data has a property `count` that is more than 0.

Comment: Make sure you are updating the datasource.

Comment: If count is greater than 0, then what selection style you want?

Comment: i want to it to be default and the alpha value of the fonts to reset to 1.

Comment: then put these change in the else part. see the updated answer.

Comment: Cool it worked! I haven't thought about that. Thanks!